# PHP: Removing string count of entire array from serialized array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, update-post-meta

I have a JSON array that I'm saving in a PHP variable. I'm then serializing that array using `serialize($variable)` and saving it to the dB with the built in Wordpress function `update_post_meta()`.

The problem I'm having is that the entire serialized array is wrapped with a string count. Like so, currently being saved as:

```
s:332:"a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:5:"weeks";s:4:"cost";s:1:"3";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:1:"2";s:13:"base_modifier";s:0:"";s:4:"from";s:1:"1";s:2:"to";s:1:"4";}i:1;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:7:"persons";s:4:"cost";s:1:"6";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:1:"5";s:13:"base_modifier";s:0:"";s:4:"from";s:1:"1";s:2:"to";s:1:"2";}}";
```

I need to save it without the string count for the entire array. Desired output:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:5:"weeks";s:4:"cost";s:1:"3";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:1:"2";s:13:"base_modifier";s:0:"";s:4:"from";s:1:"1";s:2:"to";s:1:"4";}i:1;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:7:"persons";s:4:"cost";s:1:"6";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:1:"5";s:13:"base_modifier";s:0:"";s:4:"from";s:1:"1";s:2:"to";s:1:"2";}};
```

Any help with this is, as always, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your array is serialized twice and that's what gives you the addendum ... I have taken your serialize data and un serialized it twice and it came back as you wanted :

```
<?php

$ser = 's:332:"a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:5:"weeks";s:4:"cost";s:1:"3";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:1:"2";s:13:"base_modifier";s:0:"";s:4:"from";s:1:"1";s:2:"to";s:1:"4";}i:1;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:7:"persons";s:4:"cost";s:1:"6";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:1:"5";s:13:"base_modifier";s:0:"";s:4:"from";s:1:"1";s:2:"to";s:1:"2";}}";';

$arr = unserialize($ser);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr); /* Print after one unserialize */
echo '<pre>';
print_r(unserialize($arr)); /* Print with unserialize to the once unserialized*/
```

Will return:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:5:"weeks";s:4:"cost";s:1:"3";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:1:"2";s:13:"base_modifier";s:0:"";s:4:"from";s:1:"1";s:2:"to";s:1:"4";}i:1;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:7:"persons";s:4:"cost";s:1:"6";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:1:"5";s:13:"base_modifier";s:0:"";s:4:"from";s:1:"1";s:2:"to";s:1:"2";}}
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => weeks
            [cost] => 3
            [modifier] => 
            [base_cost] => 2
            [base_modifier] => 
            [from] => 1
            [to] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => persons
            [cost] => 6
            [modifier] => 
            [base_cost] => 5
            [base_modifier] => 
            [from] => 1
            [to] => 2
        )

)
```

As you can see only after two unserialize it returns back to an array... so just do one and you have what you need.